# Java | For loop, loops infinitely but there seems to be no reason why?

Tags: java, infinite-loop, nested-for-loop

As part of a homework assigment I was tasked to printout this shape here: [LinkToTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0er9z.png)

But in the code I made which can be found below, the nested for loop seems to loop **infinetley** and after reading over and making changes to the code **several** times, nothing has seemed to change.

```
  for(int y = 1; y <= 7; y++) // y-cords
  {
    for(int x = 1; y <= 7; x++) // x-cords
    {
      if(y == 1 || y == 7 || x == 1 || x == 7) // If one of the cords lies on an edge, print out #
        System.out.print("#");
      else
        System.out.print(" "); // Blank filler
    }
    System.out.println(); // Next line of shape
  }
```

Comment: Use a debugger and single-step through the program. This way you don't have to guess what "seems" to be happening, you can observe it directly.

Comment: Or you can just READ your own code.

Answer (score 3):

In your inner for loop, the condition looks at `y` instead of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

for(int x = 1; y <= 7; x++)

There is an y instead of an x

for(int x = 1; x <= 7; x++) // x